# Is the fiber product of local artinian rings again local artinian under these conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, artinian

If we have local morphisms $A\to C$ and $B \to C$ of local artinian rings then the product $A \times_C B$ need not be local artinian anymore. To see this, take $A = \mathbb{C}(x)[\epsilon]$, $B = \mathbb{C}(y)[\delta]$ and $C = \mathbb{C}(x,y)$, with the obvious ring maps sending $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to $0$. (See comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36631/fiber-product-of-local-artinian-rings).)

I'm interested what happens if we moreover assume the residue fields of $A$, $B$, $C$ to be isomorphic to a fixed field $k$, and in addition the maps $A \to C$ and $B \to C$ induce isomorphisms on residue fields. the result is true if we also assume that our rings are algebras but I'd rather not..!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at a counterexample. It is based on the example given here: [Tag 06S4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06S4)

**Lemma**: Let $k$ be a ring, let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, let $D : A \to A$ be a $k$-derivation of $A$. Then the map $f_{D} : A \to A[\epsilon]$ sending $a \mapsto a + D(a) \cdot \epsilon$ is a $k$-algebra homomorphism.

**Example**: Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, set $L := k(x)$. Set $A := L[\epsilon]$ and $B := L$ and $C := L[\epsilon]$. Let $A \to C$ be the map $a_{1} + a_{2} \cdot \epsilon \mapsto f_{\partial / \partial x}(a_{1}) = a_{1} + (\partial / \partial x)(a_{1}) \cdot \epsilon$ and let $B \to C$ be the map $b \mapsto b + 0 \cdot \epsilon$. Then an element $(a_{1} + a_{2} \cdot \epsilon , b)$ of $A \times B$ is contained in $A \times_{C} B$ if $a_{1} + (\partial / \partial x)(a_{1}) \cdot \epsilon = b$, which means $a_{1} = b$ and $(\partial / \partial x)(a_{1}) = 0$; since $k$ has characteristic $0$, the latter condition is equivalent to $a_{1} \in k$. Hence $A \times_{C} B \simeq k + L[\epsilon]$, which is not Artinian because $L$ is not a finite-dimensional $k$-module. (Note that $A,B,C$ are $L$-algebras but the above map $A \to C$ is not a map of $L$-algebras (it is only a map of $k$-algebras).)

**Remark**: (From [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317687/is-the-intersection-of-two-function-fields-over-finite-fields-again-a-function-f).) If we only impose the condition that the residue field extensions induced by $A \to C$ and $B \to C$ are finite extensions, then we have the simpler example $C := k(x)$ and $A := k(x^{2})[\epsilon]$ and $B := k((x+1)^{2})$ in which case $A \times_{C} B = k + k(x^{2}) \cdot \epsilon$.